# simple batch script for tidy up folder

Tags: batch-file, move

I put a for loop as below to my PC desktop for example, in order to move all files to a corresponding folder named by its extension.

```
for %%G in (*.*) do (
md "%%~xG" 2>nul
move "%%G" "%%~xG"
)
```

So far the script is ok just I want to improve it with the followings,

1. make folder only if it is not exist
2. make folder by parameter expansion will create a folder .jpg, but what i wanted is jpg, can I use something like set x=%%~xG, with setlocal and EnabledDelayExpansion, and then !x:~1! to trim the dot
3. Don't move the batch file itself to the bat folder created. Shall I use expansion like %f0 ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1) What's the problem? Your code doesn't (re)create an existing folder. 2: yes. 3. yes (`if not "%%~FG" == "%~f0" ...`) 4. you probably want `for %%G in (*)` ("for all files", not "for a dot") (even better `*.*` - assuming you don't want to process files without extension)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*.*) do (

    if not "%%~xa"=="" (
        set "ext=%%~xa" & set "ext=!ext:~1!"
        if not exist "!ext!" mkdir "!ext!" 2>nul

        if not "%%~fa"=="%~f0" (
            move "%%a" "!ext!\%%a" >nul
        )
    )
)
endlocal
```

While writing, I realised @Stephan 's comment is identical to this answer, so precedence to him!

Comment: it does exactly what I wanted. Just want to know why set "ext=%%~xa" & set "ext=!ext:~1!" can do the trick, supposed the first variable set ext as .jpg while the second ext as jpg, should ext not overridden by jpg? If so what is the reason. The second thing, can I understand the move "%%a" "!ext!\%%a as move foo.jpg jpg\foo.jpg, why is it not move foo.jpg foo\ instead ?

Comment: First line sets `ext` as the extension of the extracted file. Since this includes the `<point> "."`, second set just removes it, so to have a cleared folder name equal to the extension.
Secondly, `move "%%a" "!ext!\%%a"` and `move "%%a" "!ext!\"` are similar (in this case, can happen not to be the case maybe), however as you say, you should say `move "foo.jpg" "jpg\"`, that is `move "%%a" "!ext!\"`.

Comment: @NikaidoK: see `set /?` how it works. `~1` takes a substring starting from the "first" char (zerobased!, the First char is `0`, `1` is actually the second character)